# unity editor support 3.5 .net or lower, plugin targeting 4 .net is not supported by unity editor?

Tags: unity, dll

I am trying to import some libraries in my unity project but keep getting the above error. Kindly help. Also, if anyone has some some image processing within unity,please point some useful libraries.

When I changed the framework to .net 4 and added the assembly reference to my project, I could compile my unity script but still there were errors like **unloading broken assembly, this assembly can cause crashes in runtime.** and the library I am trying to add is ConvNetSharp.

Answer (score 1):

supports the 4, but it is experimental, libraries that you can use there are many and each one is adjusted to your needs, you only need to be compatible with the framework 3.5 or 4

[image]

Comment: Hi Norby, thanks a lot for your reply. I changed these settings but I still get errors like assembly is not well supported and it might break during the runtime.

Comment: You could edit the question and add the error message, so we could help you better, I had similar problems to serialize some files, the dll I used had dependencies of other 2 dll, but the error message did not say it and after searching on Google econtre in Stack Overflow that someone mentioned that, referenced that missing dll and everything was solved, (before I had tried to change the project's Framework but it did not work and I ended up using the 3.5 with the correct dll.). Sorry for my english

Comment: I would not use this dll in a project, it is in the development phase and if the dll is modified you could break my whole project. But if you need to use it, you can look for a more correct solution here,
there is more possibility of help and, as I have read, there are others with similar problems ( https://github.com/cbovar/ConvNetSharp/issues  )